# Python Palindrome Challenge

Tags: python, python-2.x, palindrome

I've been asked to write a program that tests if a given string is a palindrome or not. n is a string of length 1<=x<=10000 containing no spaces or special characters. I wrote the following in a few minutes:

```
 def run(n):
  n = n.replace('\n','')
  nprime = n[::-1]
  Bool = True
  for i in range(0,len(n)):
    if not n[i]==nprime[i]:
      Bool = False
  if Bool==True:
    print "Y"
  else:
    print "N"
```

Apparently this fails for some test case. I don't know the test case for which it fails.  I tried it out with all edge-cases I could think of and my script seems to work fine. Does anyone have any idea where it could be failing?

Comment: Any particular reason you can't use `n == n[::-1]`?

Comment: Which test case is the program apparently failing for?

Comment: My best guess for the bug is that you're not handling I/O correctly. Either you're parsing the input incorrectly, or you're not giving the output in the correct format.

Answer (score 0):

I would simplify your code to:

```
def check(inval):
    val = inval.strip().lower()
    lav = val[::-1]
    print (val == lav) and 'Y' or 'N'
```

If you would like a really generalised version use:

```
def check(inval):
    val = ''.join([l for l in inval if l.isalnum()]).lower()
    lav = val[::-1]
    result = (val == lav)
    # print result and 'Y' or 'N' # Since comments indicate some dislike this!
    return result
```

Comment: Even better, just return the equality result and let the caller deal with displaying output.

Comment: Why the error-prone `and`/`or` hack when conditional expressions exist?

Comment: No as the input is supposed to be "containing no spaces or special characters" this includes punctuation as special characters.  It does work for `check("risetovotesir")` and I have added lower to cover case changes.